# css or xpath selector: elements which have any attribute with specific value

Tags: html, css, dom, xpath, css-selectors

I want to match all elements in an HTML Dom tree which have any attribute with the value "foo". It should either be a CSS or a XPath selector.

My naive approach would be something like this as css selector:

```
*[*='foo']
```

How is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS does not define an attribute selector that takes a wildcard as its name.

XPath, however, does. The following expression should work:

```
//*[@*="foo"]
```