# JQuery select element if *any* attribute matches

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want a selector like `$(".author")` that will select an element if "author" is the value of any attribute, not just class.

E.g. `selector.text()` should give "Emily Ekins" for each of the following pages:

```
<a href="http://reason.com/people/emily-ekins" rel="author">Emily Ekins</a>
```

or

```
<bloop href="http://reason.com/people/emily-ekins" id="author">Emily Ekins</a>
```

or

```
<blah href="http://reason.com/people/emily-ekins" class="author">Emily Ekins</a>
```

or

```
<tag href="http://reason.com/people/emily-ekins" random="author">Emily Ekins</a>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Related question for CSS/XPath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634278/css-or-xpath-selector-elements-which-have-any-attribute-with-specific-value (I could not come up with a CSS selector, only an XPath expression, and I don't know for sure if jQuery supports matching any attributes since CSS doesn't...)

Comment: You should never need to do this.

Comment: @BoltClock Note that some browsers support `document.evaluate`, which takes an XPath expression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    var element = elements[i];
    var attr = element.attributes;
    for(var j=0;j<attr.length;j++){
        if(attr[j].nodeValue == 'author'){
            element.style.backgroundColor='red';
        }
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/P3RcS/4/)

Whew! That took some time. But this will check **every single attribute** of **any given element**, and if *any* attribute is `author`, it will change the background color to red.

Comment: I think you missed [a couple of attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) ;p  I know most wouldn't make sense for this case, but the question specifically asked to match **any** attribute.

Comment: @JesseB: Actually, I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: I forgot to say, the tag is not necessarily <a> either. I edited the question.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `.attributes` option; +1! =)

Comment: thank you!  How would I get the text node of the matching element? and limit the search to just the body?

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps

```
$("[id='author'],[class='author'],[name='author'],[data-random='author']").text()
```

Comment: @tarayani: HTML5 supports custom attributes if they are preceded by `data-`.

Comment: @tarayani http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Answer (score 2):

I would use @Web Developer's answer, but will add that if you're going to need to select them multiple times, then it's more efficient to save the selection as a `var`:

```
var $target = $("[id='author'],[class='author'],[name='author']");

$target.text();
```

Here's some documentation on attribute selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Home (jQuery uses Sizzle)