# Return all elements for which any attribute starts with something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm aware of `[name^="value"]` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) but is there a analogous selector (or technique) that queries all attributes starting with the given value?

I'm looking for something like `$("[*^='http://www.something.com']")`(that does not exist).

It would match all elements which contains at least one attribute with a value that begins with `http://www.something.com`.

Say:

```
<img src="http://www.something.com/image.jpg" />
<a href="http://www.something.com">Something</a>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.something.com/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Attribute name could be anything, not just `src` and `href`, even non standard attributes.

Is there a known way to do it?

Comment: This would require the entire DOM to be iterated, and each element's attributes collection be iterated I think. I could write it in JavaScript if you'd like, then you could add it as a selector extension to jQuery? It's not going to be performant, though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8371266/1586880 for a rough idea

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do something like this?  Surely there's a better solution.

Comment: @null Yep, that's basically what I would've wrote. Glad you saved me some work

Comment: Such a thing should never exist, there is *no* use case for it. You have **two** whole attributes to select and you're only interested in three types of tags, so instead of brutalizing your DOM by checking every single attribute of every single element, just write the three queries against the attributes you actually care about and be done with it: `img[src$=http://whatever],link[href$=http://whatever],a[href$=http://whatever]`. You're going to need to come up with a better real-world justification for wanting to check every attribute of every element, there's just no reason to *ever* do that.

Comment: BTW attribute starts with selector is [^=](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: @oGeez: There are an infinite number of attributes that could take a URL.  Think about `data-*` attributes.

Comment: danronmoon, fixed. null and crush, thanks! Everyone else, I have my reasons and a use case for it, there is infinite possibilities of attributes such as `data-*` and even non-conformant attributes. Performance is not an issue and I like to brutalize the DOM :D.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's a good point, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've put together some of the ideas from other answers and wrote a custom selector.

### Selector

```
$.expr[':'].hasAttrStartingWithValue = function (obj, index, meta) {

    var startsWithAttrValue = false;
    var value = meta[3];

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.attributes.length; i++) {
        var attr = obj.attributes[i];
        // attr.value starts with value
        if (attr.specified && attr.value.lastIndexOf(value, 0) === 0) {
            startsWithAttrValue = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return startsWithAttrValue;
};
```

It has not been properly tested for cross-browsing and correctness, and I'm sure that it can be further optimized, but it seems to be working well with IE 11, FF 24 and Chrome 32.

### Usage

```
// Logs every occurrence of a value in any attribute of the page
$(":hasAttrStartingWithValue('http://www.something.com')").each(function (i, e) {
    console.log(i + " - " + e.outerHTML);
});

// Matches only children of test
$("#test :hasAttrStartingWithValue('http://www.something.com')")
   .css('background-color', 'red');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/z8KPL/)**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it for img, a, and link tags, then you could do it like this:

```
var ref = '"http://www.something.com"';
var elems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[src='+ref+'], a[href='+ref+'], link[href='+ref+']'));
//do something with the elems array
```

If you want to go the other route...

[**JS Fiddle of Working Abomination in Vanilla JS**](http://jsfiddle.net/rockyjreed/LB42K/)

Code that makes me sad (query everything in sight, loops in loops, regex in loops, etc.):

```
var rx = /(^http:\/\/www.something.com)/;
var loopAgain = function () {
    for (var j = 0, leng = attrs.length; j < leng; j++) {
        if (rx.test(attrs[j].value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
var allTheThings = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'));
for (var i = 0, len = allTheThings.length; i < len; i++) {
    var attrs = allTheThings[i].attributes;
    if (loopAgain()) {
        console.log(allTheThings[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks rjreed, your "abomination" is certainly welcome. I guess that your regex implementation for [start with](http://jsperf.com/js-startswith/19) will also be able to squeeze some better performance, if I can find a smart way to create the RegExp only once and keep it in scope for every call to the selector I will update my answer to be more like yours :).

Answer (score 1):

```
function strstr (haystack, needle, bool) {
  var pos = 0;

  haystack += '';
  pos = haystack.indexOf(needle);
  if (pos == -1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    if (bool) {
      return haystack.substr(0, pos);
    } else {
      return haystack.slice(pos);
    }
  }
}
    $( document ).ready(function(){
    $('*').each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function() {
        // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
        // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
        if(this.specified) {
          if( strstr(this.value,'http://') )
            alert(this.name+'+'+this.value);
        }
      });
    });

    });
```

Alert All attributes And values...
Custom this code...
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9d7qu/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer Eskandari, I totally forgot about the `specified` property.

Comment: oh! no problem! Jquery is great language :)

Comment: i `load()` `<form>` by Ajax but `submit()` event or `on('submit',...)` not working for this . but it work when not loaded by ajax!!! Are you known whats this problem???thank!

Comment: Eskandari, ask a question and send me the link, I will surely take a look.