# JQuery selector using value, but unknown attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use JQuery to search for elements, that have a specific attribute value, regardless of the attribute tag?

Like:

```
$("[*='myvalue']")
```

should find

```
<a href="target.html" target="myvalue">...
<tr change="myvalue">...
```

The first one, because of the "target" attribute, the second one for the "change" attribute.

Is there a better solution than just iterate over all attributes?

Comment: I don't think that is possible using a selector

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371229/jquery-select-element-if-any-attribute-matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom pseudo-selector to filter over the attributes.

Following is a jQuery way.

```
$.expr[":"].attrFilter = function(elem, index, val){
    var len = $(elem.attributes).filter(function () {
        return this.value === val[3];
    }).length;
    if (len > 0) {
        return elem;
    }
};
$('body *:attrFilter("value")').hide();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pveve7dj/1/)**

The `$.expr[":"].attrFilter`, is an extension mechanism for custom selectors. You can also pass a parameter.

---

**Syntax** :

```
$.expr[':'].selector = function(elem, index, match) { 

}
```

- `elem` is the current DOM element
- `index` is the index of elem
- `match` is an array that contains all information about the custom
  selector,where the parameter passed lies at 3rd index.
  ([Reference 1](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2010/04/19/creating-a-jquery-custom-selector/),[Reference 2](https://code.google.com/p/aost/wiki/CustomJQuerySelectorInTellurium))

  - `match[0]` – contains the full pseudo-class selector call. In this example :`attrFilter("value")`
  - `match[1]` – contains the selector name only. In this example `attrFilter`
  - `match[2]` – denotes which, if any, type of quotes are used in the parameter - expression. i.e. single (‘)  or double (“). In this
    example it will be empty.
  - `match[3]` – gives us the parameters, i.e. what is contained in the brackets. In this example `value

Comment: Why do you check against val[3] (the 3rd/4th element of the "val" array)?

Comment: The `match` attribute is passed as a array, where the parameter passed lies at 3rd index/4th element. Sorry, not able to find a perfect documentation of it. You can debug the `match` and check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the same approach will be followed here also.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371229/jquery-select-element-if-any-attribute-matches)

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 var element = elements[i];
 var attr = element.attributes;
 for (var j = 0; j < attr.length; j++) {
    if (attr[j].nodeValue == 'myvalue') {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function extension that you could use to find the elements you want.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $.fn.filter_by_attr_value = function(value) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        // [].some() would be better here
        return $.grep(this.attributes, function(attr) {
            return attr.nodeValue == value;
        }).length;
    });
  };

  $('*').filter_by_attr_value('myvalue').css('background', 'lightgreen');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="target.html" target="myvalue">FOO</a>
<table>
<tr change="myvalue">
  <td>BAR</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>not me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without JQuery in plain JavaScript or VanillaJS as other moniker is called. I put include because most of the time we search substring:

```
var all  = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (el of all) for (attr of el.attributes) if (attr.nodeValue.includes("myvalue")) console.log(attr.ownerElement)
```