# CSS selector to target element class or ID using only 1 statement

Tags: css

Is there any way to effectively write something like this as a **single statement** *(this does not work)*

```
*[*^='head'] {}
```

**Goal**: Any element, any attribute, starts with 'head' *

---

rather than as two statements *(this works)*

```
*[class^='head'],*[id^='head']{}
```

---

Targets:

```
<div class="header">Hi</div>
<div id="heading">Hi</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that we can select all the attributes, if they are just `class` and `id`, of course it's possible to write it in just a rule.

Comment: I don't think we can either, but I'm curious if just maybe there is a way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634278/css-or-xpath-selector-elements-which-have-any-attribute-with-specific-value

Comment: Hanky, can I use xpath expressions in a stylesheet as selectors ?  //*[@*="foo"]

Comment: I think XPath is just a way to query the elements in **scripting**, no way in CSS.

Comment: What about XSLT stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grammar) requires attribute name to be set in `attrib`

```
attrib
  : '[' S* [ namespace_prefix ]? IDENT S*
        [ [ PREFIXMATCH |
            SUFFIXMATCH |
            SUBSTRINGMATCH |
            '=' |
            INCLUDES |
            DASHMATCH ] S* [ IDENT | STRING ] S*
        ]? ']'
  ;
```

Take a look at the `IDENT` that matches as follows:

```
ident     [-]?{nmstart}{nmchar}*
nmstart   [_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}
nonascii  [^\0-\177]
escape    {unicode}|\\[^\n\r\f0-9a-f]
unicode   \\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \n\r\t\f])?
nmchar    [_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape}
```

So you **have to** set an attribute name. It can`t be empty or asterisk (while its namespace can).

In summary: **you can`t** match ANY attribute (at least, CSS syntax doesn`t allow it).

Answer (score 1):

There is no selector to do that, but with a bunch of jQuery code you can accomplish it:

Example: http://www.jqversion.com/#!/4FPyqGD

```
var elements = [];
$('div').each(function(){
    var s = $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    var pattern = new RegExp('="head.*"');
    if (pattern.test(s)) {
        elements.push($(this));
    }
});
console.log(elements);
```

Example using @KingKing regex: http://www.jqversion.com/#!/4FPyqGD/1

Comment: Some programmers doesn\`t use any quotes when are not necessary, like `class=short`

Comment: Guys, this is just an example, the Regular Expression might be changed by each programmer to be used as he needs..

Comment: @MateiMihai you can optimize the regular expression to this `=\\s*('|"|)head[^'"]*\\1` which accepts both pairs of single quotes or double quotes or neither and some spaces between the equal sign and the attribute value.

Comment: Thanks @KingKing I've replaced the regex with yours

Comment: @MateiMihai wow, it's interesting that the `html()` **automatically** standardizes all the quotes (singles are converted to double quotes, if not specify, double quotes are added ...), so your original code is very OK.

Comment: :) This is new for me too, I've always used double quotes and that's why never knew about this.. I'll change back to the original answer

Answer (score -3):

```
You can try this

div[class^="head"]   - for classes starting with 'head',   
div[class*="head"]   - for classes having with 'head' anywhere in class name ,  
div[class$="head"]   - for classes ends with 'head'
```

Comment: Yet another incorrect answer. Your answer does not provide matching ANY attribute, for example, it will not match `data-part=head`